# why printf behaves differently when we try to print character as a float and as a hexadecimal?

Tags: c

I tried to print character as a float in printf and got output 0. What is the reason for this.
Also:

```
char c='z';
printf("%f %X",c,c);
```

is giving some weird output for hexadecimal while output is correct when I do this:

```
printf("%X",c);
```

why is it so?

Comment: please show the incorrect output

Comment: For the `"%f"` it attempts to load 8 bytes from the stack. Then, for the "%X"` it attempts to load another 4 bytes from the stack. But when you call it with two `char`s, you only push two units of 4 bytes into the stack, so `printf` is essentially "missing" 4 out of 12 bytes that it attempts to load from the stack. At this point, pretty much anything can happen. Either it will successfully load 4 bytes of "junk" (unknown) data, or it will perform a memory access violation while attempting to load them from an invalid memory address.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please always be sure to show complete output from your examples... note that *"some weird output"* is not as useful as showing exactly what output you got.  See also the [Markdown guide](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for help on using formatting of code and other things.

Comment: output is like this 0.000000 401716, i don't understand where this 401716 came from?

Comment: @MM123: Read my comment above, it explains where that "junk" data must have come from.

Answer (score 2):

The `printf()` function is a *variadic* function, which means that you can pass a variable number of arguments of unspecified types to it. This also means that the compiler doesn't know what type of arguments the function expects, and so it cannot convert the arguments to the correct types. (Modern compilers can warn you if you get the arguments wrong to `printf`, if you invoke it with enough warning flags.)

For historical reasons, you can not pass an integer argument of smaller rank than `int`, or a floating type of smaller rank than `double` to a variadic function. A `float` will be converted to `double` and a `char` will be converted to `int` (or `unsigned int` on bizarre implementations) through a process called the *default argument promotions*.

When `printf` parses its parameters (arguments are *passed to* a function, parameters are what the function *receives*), it retrieves them using whatever method is appropriate for the type specified by the format string. The `"%f"` specifier expects a `double`. The `"%X"` specifier expects an `unsigned int`.

If you pass an `int` and `printf` tries to retrieve a `double`, you invoke *undefined behaviour*.
If you pass an `int` and `printf` tries to retrieve an `unsigned int`, you invoke *undefined behaviour*.

*Undefined behaviour* may include (but is not limited to) printing strange values, crashing your program or (the most insidious of them all) doing exactly what you expect.

Source: [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) (The final public draft of the current C standard)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a cast operator like this:

```
char c = 'z';

printf("%f %X", (float)c, c);
```

or

```
printf("%f %X", (double)c, c);
```

In Xcode, if I do not do this, I get the warning:

Format specifies specifies 'double' but the argument has type 'char', and the output is 0.000000.

Answer (score 1):

> I tried to print character as a float in printf and got output 0. What is the reason for this.

The question is, what value did you *expect* to see?  Why would you expect something other than 0?

The short answer to your question is that the behavior of `printf` is *undefined* if the type of the argument doesn't match the conversion specifier. The `%f` conversion specifier expects its corresponding argument to have type `double`; if it isn't, all bets are off, and the exact output will vary.

Answer (score 0):

To understand the floating point issue, consider reading: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point

As for hexadecimal, let me guess.. the output was something like... 99?

This is because of encodings.. the machine has to represent information in some format, and usually that format entails either giving meanings to certain bits in a number, or having a table of symbols to numbers, or both

Floating points are sometimes represented as a (sign,mantissa,exponent) triplet all packed in a 32 or 64 bit number - characters are sometimes represented in a format named ASCII, which establishes which number corresponds to each character you type

Answer (score -1):

Because printf, like any function that work with varargs, eg: `int foobar(const char fmt, ...) {}` tries to interpret its parameter to certain type.

If you say `"%f"`, then pass `c` (as a `char`), then `printf` will try to read a `float`.

You can read more here: [var_arg](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdarg/va_arg/) (even if this is C++, it still applies).